# Where can I find a comprehensive reference for CSS and its syntax?

Tags: css, syntax, reference, menu, formatting

I'm trying to build a purely CSS navigation menu which I know can be done. I've seen it. I could copy other people's but I'd rather understand what is happening myself than just copy/paste all the time.

In an effort to understand the CSS I'm running into questions I cannot manage to find anywhere on the internet and w3schools has nothing on the subject.

It took me a while to figure out what the difference was between `#nav ul {...}` and `#nav ul ul{...}` because w3schools assumes you'll never need to do anything other than the absolute basics.

My current problems:

What is `.sf-sub-indicator` ? Sounds self explanatory but I'd like to know exactly what that's doing.

What is `sfHover` as seen in `#nav li.sfHover {...}`

and lastly, what is the significance of using `>` in the CSS Class IDs? EX:

```
#nav li:hover>ul
```

as opposed to

```
#nav li:hover ul {...}
```

or

```
#nav li:hover > a {...}
```

I don't see any sort of explanation for these issues on w3schools and I don't know where else to look?

Comment: `>` is the direct descendant operator, it will only match the immediate child, not children of children. It has nothing to do with a parent matching an ID, class, or tag name. Also, sitepoint: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css

Comment: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/propindex/all.htm

Comment: The [level 3 selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) should give you a pretty good idea.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why you **shouldn't** learn through w3schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you ever wanted about CSS, JavaScript, and HTML... instantly: http://dochub.io/#css/

Answer (score 2):

The best resource for learning about CSS selectors is the World Wide Web Consortium's CSS Selectors page: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html (The Selectors Level 3 entry is the updated version, found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Read this and then it's easier to Google for additional information, since you'll have, at least, an understanding of what you're searching for.

Comment: A more canonical and up to date link: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors (though I have no idea if this will be updated when level 4 ships, or if that spec will live at /selectors4 instead; it's currently identical to /css3-selectors)

Comment: Yeah, was adding as you were commenting.